# c# when crop an image black border appear

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crop, rectangles, drawrectangle

Sorry for my English. I'm trying to crop an image after dragging. It works but my problem is, black bold borders appears on cropped image. I don't know how to solve it.

Here is my code:

```
using (Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(fullSizeImage))
{
    Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
    using (Bitmap newBitMap = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height))
    {
       using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitMap))
       {
           g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
           g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
           g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
           g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
           g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, pp, sourceWidth, sourceHeight), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
           g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
           ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()[4];
           EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
           parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
           newBitMap.Save(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is  cropped image:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your destination image is the same physical size, because you use the same physical dimensions to create it:

```
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
```

When you draw the original image into this new bitmap, you draw it with an offset `pp`, but still with the same height and width (so you're only cropping the bottom and right). This offset "colours" the memory of the new bitmap only from that y-coordinate downwards, and hence you have the black border.

Comment: i changed my codes into this:
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight-pp);

and

 g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, pp, cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
But still i see this black colours. And maybe i didn't understand you clearly because my english is not good enough

Comment: Dont draw at `(0, pp,` but at `(0, 0, `  instead. That is the top left corner.

Comment: i still do somethings wrong :/ i want that: if i drag image to top, crop image from bottom; if i drag image to bottom, crop imafe from top. Now black borders don't appear but it does not crop as what i want. 
code is like that:

 Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(0, pp, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);
  g.DrawImage(sourceBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height-pp), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

Comment: Right, so don't use the `pp` offset on the second parameter `destRect`. This rectangle should be the entire surface of the new image. Use the `pp` offset on the third parameter `sourceRect`, to define the area that you want to draw from. Also, your `cropRect` variable should be `sourceHeight - pp`, to make it smaller.

Comment: To crop from either top or bottom, you would have to either subtract `pp` from the bottom right corner (cropping bottom `sourceWidth, sourceHeight -
 pp`) or add `pp` to the top left corner (cropping from top `0, pp`)

Comment: cropping from bottom works! but cropping from top cropping wrong and still see the black lines ( cropRect = new Rectangle(0, pp, sourceWidth, sourceHeight);)

if pp is negative integer, is it problem for me?

Comment: i solve it. i changed the negative pp to positive and it works. Thank you!